# Datetime not serializable in CloudWatch API call (Unable to marshal response)

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to make a call to the CloudWatch `get_metric_data` API in Lambda using python/boto3. According to [this doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.get_metric_data), the `StartTime` and `EndTimes` should be datetime types, which is what I am using. I am stuck on how to format the `StartTime` and `EndTime` fields.

I tried using int/string timestamps and also converting the datetime using `json.dumps(datetime(2019, 8, 29), default=str)` as well as `datetime(2019, 8, 29).isoformat()`

#### Lambda code

```
import json
import boto3
from datetime import datetime 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('cloudwatch', region_name = 'us-east-1')
    metricData = client.get_metric_data(
        MetricDataQueries=[
            {
            'Id': 'numberOfCalls',
            'MetricStat': {
                'Metric': {
                    'Namespace': 'AWS/Connect',
                    'MetricName': 'QueueSize',
                    'Dimensions': [
                        {
                             'Name': 'InstanceId', 
                            'Value': 'a351243b-6844-41b0-97d9-934414342d87'
                        }, 
                        {
                            'Name': 'MetricGroup', 
                            'Value': 'Queue'
                        }, 
                        {
                        'Name': 'QueueName', 
                        'Value': 'MiWorkspace'
                    }
                ]
            },
            'Period': 300,
            'Stat': 'Maximum',
            'Unit': 'Count'
        },
        'Label': 'Retrieves the number of MiWorkspace calls in queue',
        'ReturnData': True
    },
],
StartTime=datetime(2019, 8, 29),
EndTime=datetime(2019, 8, 30),
ScanBy='TimestampAscending'
)
return metricData
```

#### Error

```
  "errorMessage": "Unable to marshal response: datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzlocal()) is not JSON serializable",
  "errorType": "Runtime.MarshalError"
```

Comment: This is not related to the way you're setting the StartTime and EndTime but to the fact that you're returning the `metricData` object from lambda. Try just logging the `metricData` object and returning something else (like an empty string) as a test.